# Drawing a card, and calling it

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a game of blackjack. I have setup a card deck and I just need to implement the game now.

So I have a a file called `deck.cpp` which contains the deck array, and a card file that stores the value and what not. In `deck.cpp` file I have the following function that can draw a card:

```
void Deck::draw(int v){
    cout << deck[v].toString();
}
```

Then, in my other file where I actually play the game, I called the deck class, and shuffled it and that is also working properly.

```
#include "Deck.hpp"
#include "PlayingCard.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class Blackjack{

    private:
        //Must contain a private member variable of type Deck to use for the game
        Deck a;
        int playerScore;
        int dealerScore;

        bool playersTurn();
        bool dealersTurn();

    public:
        //Must contain a public default constructor that shuffles the deck and initializes the player and dealer scores to 0
        Blackjack();

        void play();
};
```

Now I am having trouble figuring out how to draw the two cards print them out and get the sum of them:

```
#include "Blackjack.hpp"
#include "Deck.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
//Defaults the program to run
Blackjack::Blackjack(){
    a.shuffle();
    playerScore = 0;
    dealerScore = 0;
}
void Blackjack::play(){

}
```

I realized there might be a problem with this because when the user decides to hit, we may not know which card are in the deck. Which believes me to think that the draw function is wrong.

The problem is I can't figure out how to draw the card properly from the deck (with decrementing the top card). Then how do I adjust the userscore also. I have a `getValue()` function which returns the double.

Comment: Could you please state clearly what exactly you want and what is the problem. Draw function is wrong is quite vague.

Comment: One thing to remember about C++ is effective use of the Standard Library and its containers is the key to solving problems. `std::vector` is a good choice for general purpose arrays.

Comment: We haven't really gone over vectors yet, so not sure if we can use them. Sure he wouldn't be opposed. The problem is I can't figure out how to draw the card properly from the deck (with decrementing the top card). Then how do I adjust the userscore also. I have a getValue function which returns  the double.

Comment: @John, what you want is a set, from which you can draw items without replacement (e.g. without putting them back into deck). I would advise using `std::set` and overload `operator<` for your `PlayingCard`. You can emulate it using bool array, but it gets ugly quite fast. The other thing to do is to put drawn cards to the back of array and decrement size.

Comment: Ok yeah, just a intro class so I'm guessing it wasn't meant to be to complicated. Figured somewhere I was overlooking this and had to be a easier way.

Comment: Draw function is almost certainly wrong. Other than printing a string version of the card it doesn't do anything. You'd expect it to at least be marked as drawn or removed from the array. Most likely the card should be returned to the caller so they can do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Changes required in the Deck**

In the real world, the deck knows how many cards are left and what's the next one.  In your class it should be the same:

```
class Deck{       
   private:
        PlayingCard deck[52];
        int next_card;         //<=== just one approach 
   public:
        ...
};
```

When you draw a card in the real world,  you have the card in your hand.  So drawing returns something:

```
class Deck{       
        ...
   public:
        Deck();
        void shuffle();
        void printDeck();
        PlayingCard draw();   // <=== return the card
};
```

The function would then look like:

```
PlayingCard Deck::draw(){
    int v=next_card++; 
    cout << deck[v].toString();
    return deck[v]; 
}
```

In this implementation, `deck` is not changed for simplicity sake. When the deck is constructed, `next_card` should be initialized to 0. At any time the elements below `next_card` were already drawn, and the elements remaining on the deck are those starting from `next_card` to 51. You should also handle the case if someone wants to draw a card despite there's no card left in the deck.

**How to go on with the game**

The drawing is easier, because now, the game can know the card that was drawn.  This allows you to update the scores, bases on the `PlayCard` value.  And you no longer need to keep track of the top card:

```
Blackjack::Blackjack(){
    // Deck a;   <====== this should be a protected member of Blackjack class           
    a.shuffle();
    playerScore = 0;
    dealerScore = 0;
}
```

I'm not sure that players can draw only 2 cards.  So I'd suggest to change your game play to have a loop.

```
void Blackjack::play(){
    bool player_want_draw=true, dealer_want_draw=true;
    while (player_want_draw || dealer_want_draw) {
        if (player_want_draw) {
            cout<<"Player draws ";
            PlayCard p = a.draw(); 
            cout<<endl; 
            // then update the score and ask user if he wants to draw more
        }
        if (dealer_want_draw) {
            cout<<"Dealer draws ";
            PlayCard p = a.draw(); 
            cout<<endl; 
            // then update the score and decide if dealer should continue drawing
        }        
    }
    // here you should know who has won
}
```

You can implement a blackjack game without having to remember the value of each player's drawn cards, by updating the score and some flags at each round.  However, if you prefer, you can implement it as in the real world, by keeping in `Blackjack` for each player/dealer the cards that he/she has drawn.  With arrays, it's possible but cumbersome.  But if you have already learned about vectors, then go for it.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So then if I want to call something like draw I tried calling like a.draw(); I inialized the deck which has the draw fuction as a in the constructor also.

Comment: @John it's important that the deck `a` is made a member of the Blackjack class; otherwise you'd loose its state.  The deck is then automatically constructed in the construction process of Blackjack: no need for an additional init.

Comment: Can I just make it a private member, or does it have to be a protected member? would it just be Deck a;?

Comment: so I tried doing a private instance of Deck by calling just Deck; and it still says no name type

Comment: I suppose that you have deck.cpp for the implementation, but also deck.h for he class definitions of Deck and PlayCard, and that you `#include` this header both in deck.cpp and blackjack.cpp, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes I have, I updated my original post of where the problem is. says I'm giving it a redefinition

Comment: @John ok, I think it's because you include Blackjack.hpp before Deck.hpp, and same for Deck.hpp before PlayingCard.hpp.  As Blackjack's class definition uses a Deck, Dec.hpp must be included first.